# WordPress permalinks do not work with non-Plain setting (e.g. Month and name)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

TL;DR

- `mod_rewrite` is loaded
- `.htaccess` is writable
- `AllowOverride ALL` is set
- `LogLevel debug` is set
- logs reveal a redirect loop (see below)

---

## details

The WordPress blog is located in filesystem location `/var/www/html/` (i.e. `index.php` is in there, as are all the `wp-*.php` files such as `wp-settings.php`).

The WordPress blog's **General Settings** for **WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)** are both set to `https://example.com/blog`.

When I set the **Permalink Settings** to **Month and name** (or anything other than **Plain**), the `.htaccess` file is automatically modified to contain the following `mod_rewrite` block, and the URL paths adjust accordingly, e.g. `/blog/2019/03/hello-world/`, yet the accessing the URLs results in an **Internal Server Error**.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The log reveals the following:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
AH00121: r->uri = /blog/index.php, referer: https://staging.example.com/blog/
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /blog/index.php, referer: https://staging.example.com/blog/
... the above line repeated ...
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /2019/03/10/hello-world/, referer: https://staging.example.com/blog/
```

---

### a hint of success...

With the **Permalink Settings** set to **Plain**, the `.htaccess` file is essentially empty, and the links work, though they are of the undesirable form `/?p=123`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

When I set **Custom Structure**, to `/index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/`, the blog links are updated to the format `/blog/index.php/2019/03/hello-world/` and they work, but now the URL is ugly (the `/index.php/`).

So why doesn't it work with `/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/` and the automatically set `.htaccess` directives?

**gory details**

It shouldn't matter, but for the record: this **WordPress blog** is hosted in a **Virtual Machine instance** (**VM instance**) of the **Compute Engine** of **Google Cloud Platform**.

Comment: I assume your wordpress is inside a /blog/ folder because of your .htaccess. Is it a fresh install or you're trying to move it inside this folder?

Comment: No -- maybe I should have mentioned that within the filesystem the WordPress blog is located under `/var/www/html/` -- I have now added this information to the top of my question. That said, @JarekBaran has successfully answered my question. Nevertheless, thank you very much for trying to help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `/blog` from the last rule (`RewriteBase` stays as before).

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```